# Swift - TableViewCell - Layout margin not working

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, comments

I have a table view which should display comments with their replies. Whenever the replies are shown, there should be a margin on the left side so it is clear that a particular reply belongs to the comment above.

To achieve that, I tried following:

```
class CommentsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

// label containing name of comment writer 
private func initSenderLabel() {
    senderLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.contentView.addSubview(senderLabel)
    senderLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 18).isActive = true
    senderLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    senderLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 6).isActive = true
    senderLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:14).isActive = true
    senderLabel.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
    senderLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    senderLabel.textColor = .gray
}

// actual comment
private func initCommentLabel() {
    commentLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.contentView.addSubview(commentLabel)
    commentLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 18).isActive = true
    commentLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 209).isActive = true
    commentLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.senderLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 2).isActive = true
    commentLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -29).isActive = true
    commentLabel.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
    commentLabel.textColor = .black
    commentLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    commentLabel.numberOfLines = 0
}

// button to load replies
private func initLoadReplyButton() {
    loadReplyButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.contentView.addSubview(loadReplyButton)
    loadReplyButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
    loadReplyButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    loadReplyButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: commentLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    loadReplyButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24).isActive = true
    loadReplyButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loadReplyButton_touched), for: .touchDown)
    loadReplyButton.setTitle(NSLocalizedString(LOAD_REPLIES_BUTTON_TITLE, comment: ""), for: .normal)
    loadReplyButton.backgroundColor = .clear
    loadReplyButton.setTitleColor(.darkGray, for: .normal)
}

// Sets up the cell using the comment data
func setup(comment: Comment, sender:String) {
    // Assign comment
    self.commentObject = comment
       
    // Update UI depending if it is a comment or reply
    if comment is CommentReply {            
        loadReplyButton.isHidden = true
        contentView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 150, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
    
    else {
        // Remove insets
        loadReplyButton.isHidden = false
           
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
        updateButtonTitle()
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    }
    
    if !comment.hasReplies {
        loadReplyButton.isHidden = true
    }
        
    // Update size layout
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

However, the code above still shows me the replies as it does for the "normal" comments. How can I modify the position of the replies?

Comment: Have you tried nesting a custom UITableViewCell responsible for showing the replies inside the TableViewCell up above? This way you don't need to update the UI every time

Comment: Hi @oneshot I haven't tried that. Could you help me with a code snippet, please? Not sure how I would do that